# Visiting Israel with Tunisian stamp and Russian visas

Tags: visas, passports, israel, tunisia

I am planning to visit Israel for a week of vacation next month and realize I have a stamp from Tunisia in my passport, from three years ago and also for vacation.

Would this make any trouble visiting Israel?

I have also few Russian visas for work in my passport as well, what about those?

Comment: I found this https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/middle-east/israel/entering-israel-with-a-tunisian-stamp but its over 7 years old, not sure if still valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have little to no problems related to the issues you mention, unless you have other issues you haven't mentioned. People with visas from Arab countries routinely visit Israel. The problem comes when people with Israeli visas and stamps try visiting some Arab countries.

You have nothing to worry about concerning the Russian visa.

http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Politics-And-Diplomacy/Putin-reaffirms-mutual-ties-470690

Happy travels.

Comment: Agreed.  I've had zero issues entering Israel multiple times despite multiple visas and stamps from countries including Saudi Arabia and UAE.